# HTML for mobile

Tags: html, wordpress

I can not figure out how to make the html to be mobile friendly ..
you can check the link down page ...
with PC its ok, but with mobile its not showing well .. 
at the page im using html and shortcodes ..
the short codes im using its only for search fields and for calandar ( list view )

```html
[add_eventon_search lang="L2"] &nbsp;
<table class="wp-list-table widefat fixed striped tags ui-sortable">
  <tbody id="the-list" data-wp-lists="list:tag">
    <tr id="tag-593" class="level-2">
      <td class="description column-description" data-colname="תיאור">

        [caption id="attachment_9235" align="alignnone" width="851"]<img class="wp-image-9235 size-full" title="כרטיסים וחבילות להופעות של א-הא | A-ha | א הא הופעה | א-הא take on me | א-הא בישראל | א-הא ישראל | א הא הופעה | א הא כרטיסים | א הא | א-הא בהופעה | להקת א הא בישראל | הופעה של א-הא בארץ | הופעת א-הא | "
          src="https://myexample.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/אהא-כותרת.png" alt="כרטיסים וחבילות להופעות של א-הא | A-ha | א הא הופעה | א-הא take on me | א-הא בישראל | א-הא ישראל | א הא הופעה | א הא כרטיסים | א הא | א-הא בהופעה | להקת א הא בישראל | הופעה של א-הא בארץ | הופעת א-הא | "
          width="851" height="315" /> כרטיס וחבילה להופעה של א-הא | A-ha | א הא הופעה | א-הא כרטיסים | א-הא בהופעה |[/caption]
        <h3></h3>
        <h2 style="text-align: center;">כרטיסים וחבילות להופעות של א-הא | A-ha | א-הא כרטיסים</h2>
        <p style="text-align: right;">הופעת א-הא, הלהקה הפופ הנורווגית משנות ה-80 והמוכשרת יוצאת למסע הופעות. הכרטיסים נחטפים – אז מהרו להבטיח את מקומכם! כרטיסים להופעה של <a href="https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90-%D7%94%D7%90" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">א-הא</a>          בישראל ובכל היעדים זמינים עתה <a href="https://myexample.com">בטיקאייר</a>. ניתן לרכוש כרטיסים בלבד להופעה של <a href="https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90-%D7%94%D7%90" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">א הא</a> הופעה או חבילה הכוללת
          כרטיסים להופעות ומותאמת לכם באופן אישי. שאלו את נציג המכירות של <a href="https://myexample.com">טיקאייר</a> על חבילות מיוחדות להופעה של <a href="https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90-%D7%94%D7%90" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">א-הא</a>          בהופעה ביעד המועדף עליכם. סיבוב הופעות, <strong>כרטיסים וחבילות להופעות של א-הא</strong> בהופעה בכל היעדים.</p>

        <h2 style="text-align: right;"><span id="ההרכב" class="mw-headline">ההרכב של א הא הופעה</span></h2>
        <p style="text-align: right;">להקת א-הא הוקמה בשנת 1982 על ידי הסולן מורטן הארקט, הקלידן מאגנה פיורהולמן והגיטריסט פול וואקטר-סאבוי. תחילה פעלה הלהקה בנורווגיה, אך לאחר זמן קצר עברה ללונדון במטרה להיחשף בפני קהל רב יותר. עוד בתחילת דרכם של הלהקה, כרטיסים להופעות א הא כרטיסים
          נמכרו בהמוניהם בעיקר באירופה. את השם בחרו חברי הלהקה מתוך כוונה ליצור שם שייקלט בכמה שיותר שפות, ושמבטא קריאת כוונה והבנה בכל השפות. "א-הא" הוא שם קליט, קצר, ברור ומקורי.</p>

        <h2 style="text-align: right;"><span id="הפריצה_הגדולה_(1984_-_1985)" class="mw-headline">הפריצה הגדולה (1984 - 1985)</span></h2>
        <p style="text-align: right;">בשנת 1984 הקליטו חברי א-הא את שירם הראשון, שנקרא באותה העת "Lesson one" (שיעור ראשון). השיר נכשל באופן מוחלט ומכר רק 300 סינגלים. עובדה זו לא פגעה בנחישותם של חברי הלהקה, שהמשיכו להקליט ולערוך גרסאות נוספות לשיר, אשר קיבל בסופו של דבר את השם "Take
          on Me". השיר הפך עד מהרה ללהיט ענק, ניצב בראשי מצעדי הפזמונים באירופה ובארצות הברית ומכר למעלה ממיליון וחצי עותקים בחודש הראשון להוצאתו. אחת הסיבות להצלחתו האדירה של השיר "Take on Me" הייתה העובדה שהשיר לווה בווידאו קליפ יצירתי במיוחד, שבו נעשה
          שילוב בין אנימציה למציאות. בטקס פרסי MTV בשנת 1986 זכה השיר בשש קטגוריות שונות. מה שזיכה את הלהקה במכירה מטורפת, כרטיסים להופעות של א הא הופעה נמכרו בהמונם.</p>

        <h3>אלבומים כרטיסים להופעות</h3>
        <p style="text-align: right;">הסינגל הבא שהוציאה הלהקה היה ".The Sun Always Shines on T.V". שיר זה, שהפך גם הוא ללהיט במצעדי הפזמונים, לווה בקליפ מרהיב שזכה במספר פרסים. הלהקה מילאה אולמות, כרטיסים להופעות של להקת א-הא בהופעה של פעם בחיים נמכרו למעריצים. באותה שנה הייתה א-הא
          בין המועמדות לפרס הגראמי על הפריצה הגדולה לאותה שנה.</p>

        <h3 style="text-align: right;">ההצלחה באירופה</h3>
        <p style="text-align: right;">בעוד שבארצות הברית דעכה הצלחת הלהקה לאחר הוצאת שני הסינגלים המצליחים עמם פרצו לתודעה, הרי שבאירופה הייתה זו רק ראשית דרכה של הלהקה הצעירה מנורווגיה. אלבום הבכורה של הלהקה, "Hunting High and Low", שיצא בשנת 1985 הכיל את שני הלהיטים המצליחים ואת
          שיר הנושא, והפך לרב מכר עולמי.
          <span style="font-family: inherit; font-size: inherit;">בארצות הברית מכר האלבום למעלה ממיליון עותקים והפך לאלבום פלטינה. עד לשנת 2005 מכר האלבום 8 מיליון עותקים.
    </span>מהרו לתפוס את מקומכם, א הא הופעה יוצר לדרך, החלה מכירת כרטיסים להופעות של להקת א-הא בהופעה<strong>.</strong></p>
        &nbsp;
        <h2 style="text-align: center;">⌊ כרטיסים וחבילות להופעות של א-הא | A-ha | א-הא הופעות ⌋</h2>
        <table style="border-radius: 15px 50px; height: 222px; background: #73AD21; padding: 20px; width: 100%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
          <tbody>
            <tr style="border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;">
              <td style="width: 189px; text-align: center;">
                <h3><span style="color: #000000;"><strong>הירשם למידע העדכני ביותר על אירועי מופע הקרובים של א-הא. היה הראשון לדעת מתי הכרטיסים  יימכרו!</strong></span></h3>
              </td>
              <td style="border-radius: 0px 10px 0px 0px; width: 289px; text-align: center;">[newsletter_signup_form id=3]</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="width: 189px; text-align: center;" colspan="2"><span style="color: #ffffff;"> בהרשמת לניוזלטר שלנו אתה מסכים לקבל אימיילים על אירועים קרובים ומבצעים מיוחדים. אתה יכול לשנות את הגדרות הדוא"ל שלך בכל עת והנתונים שלך יהיו מוגנים על ידי <a style="color: #ffffff;" href="http://myexample.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">מדיניות הפרטיות</a> שלנו.</span></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <p style="text-align: center;"></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div style="border-radius: 15px; background: #ffcccc; padding: 00px; width: 100%; height: 80px; text-align: right;">
  <h3 style="text-align: right; line-height: 0.7; padding-right: 40px;"><strong><span style="color: #ffffff;">
    <img src="https://myexample.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Tickets-Icon.png" width="30" height="30" /><span style="color: #800000; line-height: 0.7;"> כמות הכרטיסים להופעות מוגבלת  </span></span></strong></h3>
  <p style="padding-right: 40px;"><span style="color: #800000; line-height: 0.7;">     גם אם ההופעה בעוד מספר חודשים הזמינות והמחיר עלולים להשתנות ועל כן מומלץ למהר ברכישה   </span></p>

</div>
&nbsp;
<div style="border-radius: 5px; width: 48%; float: left; height: 110px; background: #204060; margin: 0px; text-align: right;">
  <h1 style="text-align: right; padding-right: 40px;"><span style="color: #ffffff;"> איתור הופעות </span></h1>
  <div style="display: inline-block; width: 90%; text-align: center; padding-right: 40px;">[add_eventon_search lang="L2" ]</div>
</div>
<div style="border-radius: 5px; width: 48%; float: right; height: 110px; background: #204060; margin: 0px; text-align: center;">
  <div style="float: right;">
    <h1 style="text-align: right; padding-right: 40px;"><span style="color: #ffffff;">עדכון הופעות </span></h1>
  </div>
  <div style="float: center;"><span style="color: #ffffff;">[evo_subscribe_btn btn_txt="לחץ כאן לבחירת האומנים" add_eventon lang="L2" ] </span></div>
  &nbsp;
  <p style="text-align: right; padding-right: 40px;"><span style="color: #ffffff;"> קבלת התראות לכל האומנים האהובים עליך עכשיו בלחיצת כפתור</span></p>
</div>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; [add_eventon_list number_of_months="12" ux_val="4" event_past_future="future" event_organizer="4184" show_year="yes" hide_empty_months="yes" add_eventon lang="L2"]
```

[click here](https://myexample.co.il/product-category/%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%95%D7%97%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%95%D7%97%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A2%D7%94-%D7%A9%D7%9C-%D7%90-%D7%94%D7%90/) to view the example page.

hope some expert can help ...

Comment: This is an extremely vague question. Stack Overflow deals with __specific__ programming problems.

Answer (score 1):

First off I would NOT recommend inline styling. Convert your styles from inline to a separate CSS file.  Then within the CSS file you can use MEDIA QUERIES for custom styles based on the width of the viewport.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

This example shows styes which are only for devices under 767px wide:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .example {
           width: 50%;
      }
 }
```

While this example would be for the same class but not not under 767px:

```
 .example {
      width: 100%;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the @mediaguru's answer, you can either use media queries to make it responsive (mobile friendly) or you can use [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) to write responsive HTML pages.

If you opt for bootstrap, then you might have to re-write your HTML but it's worth writing the page again.

Media queries can be confusing and hard to maintain as you'll have to manually support different screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

AT FIRST, move your inline styles to an external style to be able to make it responsive (mobile friendly). then you need to learn and use media query.

the W3schools tutorial helps you:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp